# Stored procedure doesn't insert data into one of the table even though data looks good

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert data into two tables `[Product].`, it's inserting into one of the tables not inserting `[Product]. It returns an empty table. Not sure how to handle multiple inserts in the stored procedure:

Comment: I'd guess that your SELECT.. INNER JOIN doesn't return what you think it should, but without real data it's difficult to tell. You can run your SELECT.. INNER JOIN outside of the procedure with mock data to see if it works.

Comment: You should probably be using *exists* here, not a join. What is the data type of the joining column? Have you checked the output of string_split? You are in a much better posititon to debug your data than we are.

Comment: You could use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to extract the rows inserted from the first `INSERT` so you can reference them in the second `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 INSERT INTO [Product].[LKStandardProductGroup]
([StandardProductGroupID],[StandardProductID])
 SELECT      
       @StandardProductGroupID as [StandardProductGroupID] ,
       value as [StandardProductID] 
    FROM        STRING_SPLIT(@StandardProductCodes,',') inp
    INNER JOIN  [Product].[StandardProduct] sp WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON          sp.[StandardProductID] = inp.value
```